# Where are defined default git commit/cherry-pick/merge messages?

Tags: git

A sample of `prepare-commit-msg` is given by the file `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample` whose content is as follow.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to prepare the commit log message.
# Called by "git commit" with the name of the file that has the
# commit message, followed by the description of the commit
# message's source.  The hook's purpose is to edit the commit
# message file.  If the hook fails with a non-zero status,
# the commit is aborted.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "prepare-commit-msg".

# This hook includes three examples. The first one removes the
# "# Please enter the commit message..." help message.
#
# The second includes the output of "git diff --name-status -r"
# into the message, just before the "git status" output.  It is
# commented because it doesn't cope with --amend or with squashed
# commits.
#
# The third example adds a Signed-off-by line to the message, that can
# still be edited.  This is rarely a good idea.

COMMIT_MSG_FILE=$1
COMMIT_SOURCE=$2
SHA1=$3

/usr/bin/perl -i.bak -ne 'print unless(m/^. Please enter the commit message/..m/^#$/)' "$COMMIT_MSG_FILE"

# case "$COMMIT_SOURCE,$SHA1" in
#  ,|template,)
#    /usr/bin/perl -i.bak -pe '
#       print "\n" . `git diff --cached --name-status -r`
#        if /^#/ && $first++ == 0' "$COMMIT_MSG_FILE" ;;
#  *) ;;
# esac

# SOB=$(git var GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT | sed -n 's/^\(.*>\).*$/Signed-off-by: \1/p')
# git interpret-trailers --in-place --trailer "$SOB" "$COMMIT_MSG_FILE"
# if test -z "$COMMIT_SOURCE"
# then
#   /usr/bin/perl -i.bak -pe 'print "\n" if !$first_line++' "$COMMIT_MSG_FILE"
# fi
```

However, this is not the default message used by git for commit, cherry-pick and merges messages. Where can be found the default ones?

Comment: Do you need further information? If not, please consider accepting my answer so the system knows this question is answered.

Comment: Sorry @DanielB, I started looking for more info thanks to the information you posted and totally forgot to mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is hard-coded in [`commit.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/commit.c), `fmt-merge-msg.c`, ...

The logic to create these messages is not always simple.

Please note that although all human-readable messages (like the comment blocks in the commit message editor) are [localized](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/po), the actual commit messages (like “Merge branch 'x' into 'y'”) are not.